# ActivityNotFoundException in zxing

Tags: android, barcode, zxing

I am new in android. I am developing a App in which i have to used zxing for scanning bar code
and QR code. In my App i can not use third party software. That means i can't use these line of code in my App

```
 IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(shopping.this);
            integrator.initiateScan();
```

So, in that case i used these line code after reading several tutorial .

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"); 
              intent.setPackage("com.google.zxing.client.android"); 
             // intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
              intent.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", "CODE_39,CODE_93,CODE_128,DATA_MATRIX,ITF,CODABAR,EAN_13,EAN_8,UPC_A,QR_CODE");
              startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

But unfortunately this is showing Exception for me, my total log-cat output is as follow-

```
                           01-06 06:00:02.131: D/AndroidRuntime(956): Shutting down VM
                  01-06 06:00:02.131: W/dalvikvm(956): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
                  01-06 06:00:02.161: E/AndroidRuntime(956): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  01-06 06:00:02.161: E/AndroidRuntime(956): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN pkg=com.google.zxing.client.android (has extras) }
                  01-06 06:00:02.161: E/AndroidRuntime(956):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1545)
                  01-06 06:00:02.161: E/AndroidRuntime(956):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1416)
                  01-06 06:00:02.161: E/AndroidRuntime(956):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
                  01-06 06:00:02.161: E/AndroidRuntime(956):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3312)
                  01-06 06:00:02.161: E/AndroidRuntime(956):    at com.google.zxing.shopping.shopping$1.onClick(shopping.java:99)
                  01-06 06:00:02.161: E/AndroidRuntime(956):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
                 01-06 06:00:02.161: E/AndroidRuntime(956):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
                 01-06 06:00:02.161: E/AndroidRuntime(956):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                  01-06 06:00:02.161: E/AndroidRuntime(956):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                 01-06 06:00:02.161: E/AndroidRuntime(956):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                 01-06 06:00:02.161: E/AndroidRuntime(956):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
               01-06 06:00:02.161: E/AndroidRuntime(956):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                 01-06 06:00:02.161: E/AndroidRuntime(956):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                01-06 06:00:02.161: E/AndroidRuntime(956):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                 01-06 06:00:02.161: E/AndroidRuntime(956):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                01-06 06:00:02.161: E/AndroidRuntime(956):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

But when i just replace this line

```
   Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
```

to this line

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(shopping.this, CaptureActivity.class);
```

and i run my App  it successfully run for me , but problem is that it is **only scanning **QR Code , it not working for BAR code**. 
For convenience for those who want to help i am going to show my Manifest file

```
              <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.xyrad.xybuy"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.landscape" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="false" />

<application
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo_xybuy"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.maps"
        android:required="true" />

    <activity
        android:name=".RegisterCustomer"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register_customer" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- BarCodeScanner -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" ><intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <!-- Allow web apps to launch Barcode Scanner by linking to http://zxing.appspot.com/scan. -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="zxing.appspot.com"
                android:path="/scan"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- We also support a Google Product Search URL. -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="www.google.com"
                android:path="/m/products/scan"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- And the UK version. -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="www.google.co.uk"
                android:path="/m/products/scan"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- Support zxing://scan/?... like iPhone app -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="scan"
                android:path="/"
                android:scheme="zxing" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.PreferencesActivity"
        android:label="@string/preferences_name"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.encode.EncodeActivity"
        android:label="@string/share_name"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.ENCODE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- This allows us to handle the Share button in Contacts. -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="text/x-vcard" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- This allows us to handle sharing any plain text . -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.history.HistoryActivity"
        android:label="@string/history_title"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="WelcomeCustomerSplash" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="HomePage" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".buy.BuyClick" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".shoppinglistmanage.ShoppingListManageCompulsory" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".otw.OtwClick" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".buy.ClickIHaveList" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".buy.WaitToPopulateData" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".buy.ListWithDiscountNetPrice" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".buy.PaymentOption" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".buy.PurchaseItemList" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".buy.UnPurchaseItemList" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".googlemap.LocateForNearestStore" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".googlemap.WhereIam" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".paymentgateway.ShoppingPaymentGatewayPayPalActivity" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPalActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.zxing.shopping.PurchaseList"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.zxing.shopping.DeviceListActivity" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.zxing.shopping.shopping" >
    </activity>

    <!-- purchase -->
    <!-- DeviceList -->
    <activity android:name="com.google.zxing.shopping.DataLayer" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.xyrad.xybuy.ecommerce.payment.BillingAddress" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.xyrad.xybuy.ecommerce.cart.ListCart" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.xyrad.xybuy.ecommerce.category.ListCategory" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.xyrad.xybuy.ecommerce.subcategory.ListCategorySubCategory" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.xyrad.xybuy.ecommerce.subcategory.TabSubCategory" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.xyrad.xybuy.ecommerce.catalog.ListCatalog" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.xyrad.xybuy.ecommerce.checkout.ListCheckOut" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.xyrad.xybuy.ecommerce.item.ItemDetails" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.xyrad.xybuy.ecommerce.item.ListItem" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.xyrad.xybuy.ecommerce.item.ItemReview" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.xyrad.xybuy.ecommerce.merchant.ListMerchant" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.xyrad.xybuy.ecommerce.merchant.TabMerchant" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.xyrad.xybuy.ecommerce.payment.ModeOfPayment" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.xyrad.xybuy.ecommerce.offer.ListOffer" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.xyrad.xybuy.ecommerce.payment.Payment" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.xyrad.xybuy.ecommerce.category.TabCategry" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.xyrad.xybuy.ecommerce.item.TabItem" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.xyrad.xybuy.ecommerce.item.TabItemDetails" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.xyrad.xybuy.ecommerce.item.TabItemDetailsAndReview" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.xyrad.xybuy.ecommerce.deparment.ListDepartment" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.xyrad.xybuy.ecommerce.catalog.TabCatalog" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.xyrad.xybuy.ecommerce.subcategory.TabSubCategoryegory.TabSubCategoryegory.TabSubCategory" >
    </activity>
</application>

<!-- Category -->
```

So, this my description of my problem. So please some one help me . I will really thankful to all from my bottom of heart.
thanks in advance to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting ActivityNotFoundException as Zxing application is not installed in your device. So Please check whether it is installed or not. If it's not then redirect user to playstore-page of Zxing:

I've implemented some code for these. Modify it according to your needs:

```
boolean isZxingInstalled;
/*
 *Checking whether Zxing is installed or not
 */ 
try
{
ApplicationInfo info = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("com.google.zxing.client.android", 0 );
boolean isZxingInstalled = true;
    }
catch(PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e){
                isZxingInstalled=false;
          }

/*
 * Store the boolean value on the basis of Zxing is installed or not
 */

if(isZxingInstalled) //If it is then intent Zxing application
 {
         //start the facebook app
         Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
          intent.setPackage("com.google.zxing.client.android"); 
          intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
          intent.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS",    "CODE_39,CODE_93,CODE_128,DATA_MATRIX,ITF,CODABAR,EAN_13,EAN_8,UPC_A,QR_CODE");
          startActivityForResult(intent, 0); 
  }
 else //It's not then redirect user to PlayStore-ZxingPlage
  {
    /*
     *Checking whether PlayStore is installed in device or not?
     */
     boolean isPlayStoreInstalled
     try
     {
      ApplicationInfo i=getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("com.google.vending", 0 );
      boolean isPlayStoreInstalled = true;
      }
     catch(PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e){
                isPlayStoreInstalled=false;
          }

      /*
       * If it is the download Zxing
       */ 
      if(isPlayStoreInstalled)
       {
        Intent DownloadZxing = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://detailsid=com.google.zxing.client.android"));
        startActivity(DownloadZxing);
        }
      else //Toast message indicating No PlayStore Found
       {
         Toast.makeText(this,"Install PlayStore First",Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show();
        }
  }
```

Hope these may help!! :)

Comment: is it possible to scan QR and Bar code without installing any other App.??

Comment: Yes, you can embed the ZXing library in your build w/o the end user having to explicitly download it from the app store.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this 3rd party application installed in your phone or emulator where ever you are running the application?

Android operating system couldn't find the activity.

```
          01-06 06:00:02.161: E/AndroidRuntime(956): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN pkg=com.google.zxing.client.android (has extras) }
```

Use try and catch block, make sure the application is installed in your phone, if it's not : point the user to 3rd party application on playstore.

Answer (score 0):

Use the supplied IntentIntegrator class as it will handle cases that you need to handle, like the app not being installed.

Comment: @hi Sean , I know that you are among one of developer of Zxing by google((GREAT JOB !!))..I already used  IntentIntegrator , but as i told in my App i can't use such thing - when user is going to use my App , then he/she does not get any type of message to installed a scanner app. I already used zxing . So i will thankfull to if you will tell how i could i find my desire output only by code

Comment: I don't understand. You're integrating by Intent and saying you can't integrate by Intent.